# WPF prevent execute command when button got focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have application with textbox and button. When I click on ENTER in textbox, I would like to set focus on button (using traversing), but when button got focus, execute command. I dont want to execute command when button got focus. Here is my code:

**View1.xaml**

`<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown"/>`

**View1.xaml.cs**

```
 private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Key != Key.Return) return;
    TraversalRequest tRequest = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
    UIElement keyboardFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
    keyboardFocus?.MoveFocus(tRequest);
 }
```

**View2.xaml**

```
<Button Content="Testbutton" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
```

**View2Vm**

```
   class View2Vm : BaseVm
    {
      public RelayCommand TestCommand { get; set; }

      public View2Vm() 
        => TestCommand = new RelayCommand(x => { MessageBox.Show("Message"); });
    }
```

How to set focus on button without execute command? Thanks

Comment: The command isn't executed as result of setting the focus, but because the Enter KeyDown event is still there. Probably set `e.Handled`.

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyDown event is still enabled when focus was set. Solution is:

```
 private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Key != Key.Return) return;
    TraversalRequest tRequest = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
    UIElement keyboardFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
    keyboardFocus?.MoveFocus(tRequest);
    e.Handled = true;
 }
```